# How to make Vuetify component in Codepen using by Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have used `nuxt.js` in my company project. I really wanted to test easily,
so I decided to register `Codepen Pro`.
I just want to show `v-data-table` components in codepen, but it didn't work.

My code just referred to `Vuetify` website. I chose `Typescript`, `Vue` and `Vuetify` in codepen and saved.

I have been searching someone trying to make same components, but I couldn't find out.....

Does anyone know how to write `Vuetify` code in codepen?

my code is below↓

```
html    
<div id=app>
<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" :items-per-page="5" class="elevation-1"></v-data-table>
</template>
</div>




 Typescript
new Vue ({
  el=#app
  headers = [
    {
      text: "Dessert (100g serving)",
      align: "start",
      sortable: false,
      value: "name"
    },
    { text: "Calories", value: "calories" },
    { text: "Fat (g)", value: "fat" },
    { text: "Carbs (g)", value: "carbs" },
    { text: "Protein (g)", value: "protein" },
    { text: "Iron (%)", value: "iron" }
  ];
  desserts = [
    {
      name: "Frozen Yogurt",
      calories: 159,
      fat: 6.0,
      carbs: 24,
      protein: 4.0,
      iron: "1%"
    },
    {
      name: "Ice cream sandwich",
      calories: 237,
      fat: 9.0,
      carbs: 37,
      protein: 4.3,
      iron: "1%"
    }
  ];
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code.
First off, you should return the data as following:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: "Dessert (100g serving)",
          align: "start",
          sortable: false,
          value: "name"
        },
        { text: "Calories", value: "calories" },
        { text: "Fat (g)", value: "fat" },
        { text: "Carbs (g)", value: "carbs" },
        { text: "Protein (g)", value: "protein" },
        { text: "Iron (%)", value: "iron" }
      ],
       desserts: [
        {
          name: "Frozen Yogurt",
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: "1%"
        },
        {
          name: "Ice cream sandwich",
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: "1%"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Second, in order to use Vuetify you need a `<v-app>` wrapping around the content.
So your html should look something like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" :items-per-page="5" class="elevation-1"></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Here's a codepen example using vuetify that I found: https://codepen.io/charlesok/pen/yqmEXE

Note that he also added several CDNs for Vue, Vuetify and babel-polyfill in order for the Vue and Vuetify to be displayed correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I really appreciate your whole advise! Thank you so much!!